# hokuyo node not running

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

cant run hokuyo node
output

```
natan@natan-ThinkPad-T60:~$ rosdep install hokuyo_node rviz
Warning: could not identify ['hokuyo_node'] as a package
rosdep executing this script:
{{{
set -o errexit
#No Packages to install
}}}
```

what am i missing

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11019/hokuyo-node-not-running/) by [natan](https://answers.ros.org/users/960/natan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In short: You are missing the hokuyo_node package.
(Also rosdep install does not run the hokuyo node, rosrun does.)

This could be either because it is not installed (then you need to install it) or your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable is not containing the directory for the hokuyo_node.

Did you install diamondback from packages? Then you should have `/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/laser_drivers/hokuyo_node`. If that is the case `source /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.sh` and `roscd hokuyo_node` should work. If it is not there you need to install ros-diamondback-laser-drivers.

Otherwise, you need to give some more information on your system and ROS setup.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [natan](https://answers.ros.org/users/960/natan/) on 2011-08-25**:
thx lorenz workes

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-08-25**:
sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-laser-drivers

**Comment by [natan](https://answers.ros.org/users/960/natan/) on 2011-08-25**:
i do not hav /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/laser_drivers/hokuyo_node. how do i add it??